# How to fix the issue in the below code snippet

Tags: java

I am implementing the method hiding concept through inheritance.I am getting the error.

```
class Parent
{
 synchronized strictfp final static public void main(String...ab)
 {
   System.out.println("Hello,Java is better than C++");
  }                                                                      
 }  
class Child extends Parent {                       
    static public void main(String[] args)
   {

     System.out.println("Hello, C++ is better than Java");

    }    
  }
```

I am executing the program as Parent.java
javac Parent.java

### Expected

Two classes should get created 
 1.Parent.class 2.Child.class

java Parent

Hello,Java is better than C++

java Child

Hello, C++ is better than Java

### Actual

javac Parent.java

Parent.java:11: error: main(String[]) in Child cannot override main(String...) in Parent
   static public void main(String[] args)
                      ^
  overridden method is static,final
1 error

Comment: inheritance doesn't work on static methods.

Comment: Don't make the method final.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Well, static methods are implicitly "final". `final` is certainly *redundant*, but removing it will not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `final` word from Parent class declaration.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206822805-What-is-the-point-of-the-static-method-declared-final-inspection-

Answer (score 0):

When you make a method as `final` then that method cannot be overridden in any class. So you need to remove the keyword `final`.

```
class Parent
    {
     synchronized strictfp static public void main(String...ab)
     {
       System.out.println("Hello,Java is better than C++");
      }                                                                      
     }  
    class Child extends Parent {                       
        static public void main(String[] args)
       {

         System.out.println("Hello, C++ is better than Java");

        }    
      }
```